# JavaScript Form Cloning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, cloning

I am trying to clone simple "directors / members" form. When I hit "add member button" it clones everything the form, but it does not erases zip code field. Also, when I submit the form it does not submit the first two fields of the cloned forms. It takes values of first name and last name and assigns it to address and city and so on... So, to summarize it does not send two fields, and I think it's state and zip fields of cloned forms that give me troubles, but I can't see why.

```
$y=0; $clone=1; do{  ?>
    <div id="<?php echo "clonedSection$clone"; ?>" class="clonedSection" >
        <p style="margin-left:350px; font-size: 14px;"><label id="<?php echo "member_label$clone"; ?>"  >  <?php echo "Director / Member $clone"; ?></label> </p><br><br>
                <p style="margin-left:370px;">First name<input style="margin: 2px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="<?php echo "member_firstname$clone"; ?>" id="<?php echo "member_firstname$clone"; ?>" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][0];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_first_name"];?></span> </p>
                <p style="margin-left:373px; ">Last name<input style="margin: 2px;  margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="<?php echo "member_lastname$clone"; ?>" id="<?php echo "member_lastname$clone"; ?>" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][1];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_last_name"];?></span> </p>
                <p style="margin-left:350px; ">Street address<input style="margin: 2px;  margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="<?php echo "member_address$clone"; ?>" id="<?php echo "member_address$clone"; ?>" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][2];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_address"];?></span> </p>
                <p style="margin-left:405px; ">City <input style="margin: 2px;  margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="<?php echo "member_city$clone"; ?>" id="<?php echo "member_city$clone"; ?>" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][3];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_city"];?></span> </p>
                <p style="margin-left:402px;">State<select style="margin: 2px;  margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" name="<?php echo "member_state$clone"; ?>" id ="<?php echo "member_state$clone"; ?>">
                    <?php //$states = listStates(statesList());
                    foreach($states as $value){
                        echo '<option >'.$value.'</option>';
                    }  echo '<option selected>'.$split_members[$y][4].'</option>'; ?>
                </select> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_state"];?></span> </p>
                <p style="margin-left:384px;">ZIP code<input style="margin: 2px;  margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="<?php echo "member_zip$clone"; ?>" id="<?php echo "member_zip$clone"; ?>" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][5];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_zip"];?></span> </p>

            </div>
        <?php $y++; $clone++; } while ($y < count($split_members)); ?>
```

And I use the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",false);

        var num = $(".clonedSection").length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

        var newSection = $("#clonedSection" + num).clone().attr("id", "clonedSection" + newNum);

        newSection.children(":nth-child(1)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_label" + newNum);
        newSection.children(":nth-child(2)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_firstname" + newNum).attr("id", "member_firstname" + newNum).attr("value", "");
        newSection.children(":nth-child(3)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_lastname" + newNum).attr("id", "member_lastname" + newNum).attr("value", "");
        newSection.children(":nth-child(4)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_address" + newNum).attr("id", "member_address" + newNum).attr("value", "");
        newSection.children(":nth-child(5)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_city" + newNum).attr("id", "member_city" + newNum).attr("value", "");
        newSection.children(":nth-child(6)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_state" + newNum).attr("id", "member_state" + newNum).attr("value", "");
        newSection.children(":nth-child(7)").children(":first").attr("name", "member_zip" + newNum).attr("id", "member_zip" + newNum).attr("value", "");


        $(".clonedSection").last().append(newSection);

        elem = document.getElementById('member_label' + newNum);
        elem.innerHTML = "Director / Member " + newNum;

            if (newNum == 12)
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled",true);
    });

    $("#btnDel").click(function() {
        var num = $(".clonedSection").length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

        $("#clonedSection" + num).remove();     // remove the last element
        // enable the "add" button
        $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled",false);

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num-1 == 1)
        $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",true);

    });

    //$("#btnDel").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",true);
    var count = $(".clonedSection").length;
    if (count > 1)
    $("#btnDel").prop("disabled",false);
    //$("#btnDel").disabled = false;

});
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic, to set an ID, you can do `$('element')[0].id="example'`. Using native javascript is (often) faster. The same goes for `.name` (`document.getElementById('element').id="asd"` would be all javascript fyi)

Comment: And another to make your code a lot more readably, the following two act the same: `<input name="<?php echo $name"; ?>" />` and `<input name="<?= $name ?>" />`

Comment: But I can't get those elements because their IDs and Names are not unique. When I clone the form, the cloned form has fields with the same ids and names as first one. So, I can't access them to make any changes. That is why I am using the children stuff to change Ids and names

Comment: Do they have to have an ID? Why not a class? makes things a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

You're making it way more complex than needed.

If you have an input `<input name="example[0]" />` and clone that, and try to make it `<input name="example[1]" />` with weird increments and such, just use the array version:

```
<input name="example[]" value="My key will be 0" />
<input name="example[]" value="My key will be 1" />
<input name="example[]" value="My key will be 2" />
```

To use this again in php:

```
foreach($_POST['example'] as $key =>$value){
    echo $key.': '.$value.'<br />';
    echo $key.': '.$_POST['anotherName'][$key]; // (example for another variable)
}
```

As you can see, **a lot** less complicated and much easier to read and maintain. This way you can clone your form without having to worry about which number it is, you can easily loop through them.
If you aren't used to this, I still recommend to try this, maybe only in a small test setup. Controlling arrayed forms is a skill with a lot of value.

Comment: I sorry I don't get it. it's not php that fails. it's my java script cloning fails because the rest of the form is fine. I mean the form is a lot bigger than this "member" part... plus the first member that is not cloned is submitted just fine.

Comment: Your code is more complex than it has to. WAY more complex. I suggest you try my two suggestions in the comments below your topic, and after that my answer. This might not be the solution you want, but it is the solution you need.

Comment: After that, cloning your form with javascript will be easy and more simple

Comment: But really! I just print_r my Post and everything is there except two fields of cloned form! how is that possible